# Solved - SSIS - Send mail on error task sends multiple mails

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I build a SSIS-Package to import data from an excel-file. As the excel file is required to have a certain scheme, it fails sometimes if the person creating the file does not stick to the scheme. For this case, i want to send a mail to this person, informing about the fail. I tried different methods but the send mail task always sends 5 to 6 mails instead of one.

The basic structure of my package is this:

[image]

The mail task is a simple "Send Mail Task" via SMTP Connection Manager and without attachements, only a message.

Previous approaches are:

1. With the Event Handler: Settings i tried are Event Handler: OnError and Executable: Whole Package level, on the foreach loop container and on the single "Import File" Task, as this is the one that fails.
2. In the control flow: I conneted the mail task on failure with the loop container and also with the single import file task:

[image]

[image]

I also played with the "Delay Validation"-setting in the properties, setting it on true for the loop container and also the import file task.

Where is the mistake i make and how can i fix the package to send only one mail instead of 5-6? Thanks in advance!

**Update:** The Problem kinda solved itself. I changed from a send mail task to a script task to send a mail with a logfile, this worked perfectly. I also changed the mail_from in the send mail task from a mail-container to a single mail, and this also solved the problem. After that, i changed again to the mail-container and it also works how it should. Seems to be a bug. Thanks all.